# Make ul wrap, but not overlap

Tags: css, html-lists, overlap, word-wrap

I am trying to wrap ul around an image without it [overlapping](https://jsfiddle.net/9L0786rx/)

Naturally it wraps, but also overlaps. I quickly fix this with:

```
ul {  overflow:hidden;   }
```

but that removes the [wrap](https://jsfiddle.net/9L0786rx/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is your intended result, but you can do:

```
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nyknht9p/