# How to make a <ul> wrap nicely with floating elements?

Tags: css, alignment, css-float, html-lists

I have a floating image followed by an unordered list. By default, this causes the list bullets to overlap the image.

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" />
<ul>
<li>A list element.</li>
<li>An element with some text that might be long enough to wrap to the next line. That sentence won't do it, but maybe if I add another I can demonstrate this issue.</li>
<li>Another simple element</li>
<li>Number 4</li>
<li>A fifth</li>
<li>Now this one should be below the image.</li>
</ul>
```

As noted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318798/make-ul-wrap-but-not-overlap), `overflow: hidden` resolves the overlap but causes the list elements to no longer left align once the bottom of the image is reached.

`list-style-position: inside` moves the bullets outside of the image, but makes the text within the item no longer aligned consistently (i.e. the first line is offset by the bullet and the rest are aligned with the bullet instead of the first line).

```css
img {
  float: left;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" />
<ul>
<li>A list element.</li>
<li>An element with some text that might be long enough to wrap to the next line. That sentence won't do it, but maybe if I add another I can demonstrate this issue.</li>
<li>Another simple element</li>
<li>Number 4</li>
<li>A fifth</li>
<li>Now this one should be below the image.</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to do this in a way that simply does the right thing?

*Edit:* I also want to set this up in a way that allows non-list text next to the floating element to behave normally, so just adding a margin doesn't work either

Answer (score 3):

An inside configuration with some `text-indent` can fix it:

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right:1.7em; /* a litte bigger than the text-indent */
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-indent:-1.5em; /* adjust this based on your case */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" />
<ul>
<li>A list element.</li>
<li>An element with some text that might be long enough to wrap to the next line. That sentence won't do it, but maybe if I add another I can demonstrate this issue.</li>
<li>Another simple element</li>
<li>Number 4</li>
<li>A fifth</li>
<li>Now this one should be below the image.</li>
</ul>
```

Another idea using translate that will work with any kind of content:

```css
img {
  float: left;
}

ul {
  padding:0;
}
li {
  transform:translateX(1.5em);
  margin-right:1.5em;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" />
<p>An element with some text that might be long enough to wr </p>
<ul>
<li>A list element.</li>
<li>An element with some text that might be long enough to wrap to the next line. That sentence won't do it, but maybe if I add another I can demonstrate this issue.</li>
<li>Another simple element</li>
<li>Number 4</li>
<li>A fifth</li>
<li>Now this one should be below the image.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: See my edit, I need this to work for non-lists as well since these styles will be applied to user-generated content. This solution causes non-list text to be indented further than the list

Comment: Your first example is not good enough, but second is really nice!

Answer (score 1):

Redid the answer, so indeed you'll need floats for this. And as you want it to work with text as well I've added it with the answer. Lists automatically get paddings applied to them. The problem might lie there.

```css
img {
height:auto;
max-width:200px;
margin-right:20px;
float:left;
}

img {
overflow:hidden;
}

ul {
padding-left:20px;
max-width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">


<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" />

<ul>
<li>A list element.</li>
<li>An element with some text that might be long enough to wrap to the next line. That sentence won't do it, but maybe if I add another I can demonstrate this issue.</li>
<li>Another simple element</li>
<li>Number 4</li>
<li>A fifth</li>
<li>Now this one should be below the image.</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="row">


<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" />

<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>


</div>
```

Comment: That has the same issue as `overflow: hidden`: the items are all to the right of the image, while I want some of them to wrap back to the left side

Comment: Yes, misunderstood the question so I updated it!

Comment: It fixes some issues, but margin-right does not work well on image with UL and does not looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you want, but if you want all list items to appear next to your picture you could try something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .picture {
            shape-outside: initial;
            float: left;
            margin-inline-end: 1em;
            min-width: 13em;
            width: 30%;
            padding: 3px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <h1> Header </h1>
        <img class="picture" src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" />
            <ul>
                <li>A list element.</li>
                <li>An element with some text that might be long enough to wrap to the next line. That sentence won't do it, but maybe if I add another I can demonstrate this issue.</li>
                <li>Another simple element</li>
                <li>Number 4</li>
                <li>A fifth</li>
                <li>Now this one should be below the image.</li>
            </ul>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works for this specific situation, but causes any text between the image and the list to also be indented to the level of the list text

Comment: And what would you expect/desire to happen in that situation? Can you post some "*[mcve]*" code that reproduces that problem and explain - or show an image - how you'd like it to behave?

Comment: I want the difference in indentation between the text and list items to be the same as it usually is, where lists are indented further

Comment: Agreed with @DavidsaysreinstateMonica, an example would be ideal for this scenario.